# calculator issue: radians or degrees for inverse trig

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

It's a simple question but I am a little confused.  The value of $cos^{-1} (-0.5)$ ,  is it   2.0943 or 120  ?

Comment: Depends on whether you want the answer in radians or degrees.

Comment: if you are asked to draw a circle with radius $cos^{-1}(-0.5)$, should you use degrees or radians?

Comment: radians, because it's a real number (see below)

Comment: I would say that it is an odd question, you need to know the units. Just as with any measurement, telling you to draw a square of side 1 doesn't help unless you know that it is meters, inches, feet, etc...

Comment: @user84413: Degrees would be a real number too...

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think the radius of a circle would be an angle (and therefore measured in degrees or radians), but instead a real number.

Comment: I vote for:$$\cos^{-1}(-0.5)=133.333...$$ $\text{Grads}$ never get the respect they deserve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of $\cos^{-1}(x)$ as an angle, then you can express the answer in either degrees or radians.

If you think of this as a real number, though, then it always takes on a value between 0 and $\pi$ (which is numerically equal to the angle in radians).

Comment: This is incorrect. The **domain** is $[-1,1]$, and the range (using the principal value) is $[0,\pi]$ radians or $[0°, 180°]$ depending on your measurement.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, I'll correct this.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to understand that there are several different functions called cosine. I find it useful to refer to "cos" (the thing for which $\cos^{-1}(0) = \pi/2$) and "cosd" for which cosd(90) = 0.

Your calculator (if you're lucky) will mean "cos" when you press the "cos"  button; if you've got the option of "degrees/radians", then in "degrees" mode, the "cos" button is actually computing the function "cosd".

Answer (score 0):

The principal value of $\cos^{-1}(-0.5)$ is $120^{\circ}$ or $\frac{2 \pi}{3} \approx 2.0943$ radians.  Take your pick!

A couple of key points here.

First, it *helps* to have a feeling for what range of values to expect when you do an operation.  If I'm taking $\cos^{-1}x$ I expect to get an angle.  If the angle is measured in degrees, reasonable values are $0$ to $180$.  If the angle is measure in radians, reasonable values are $0$ to $\pi \approx 3.14159265$.

For angles in general, $-180$ to $360$ would be resonable for degree measures, and $-3.14159265$ to $6.2831853$ or $-\pi$ to $2\pi$ would be reasonable for radian measures.

Second, though, any intuition should be verified by *knowing* what you're looking at.  You should *know* whether you need to input angles in degrees or radians, and you should *know* whether the angles you get back are expressed in degrees or in radians.

Because if you don't know, your intuition may not be enough.  What if you're calculating $\cos(\pi / 100)$?  Here, $\pi/100$ is an angle in radians.  You enter $0.031415926535$ and push the $\cos$ key.  If you're in "radians" mode, the answer you get back is $\approx 0.999506560$, but if you're instead in "degrees" mode, the answer you get back is $\approx 0.999999849$, which is substantially a different answer, but not one that you could easily tell was wrong just by looking at it.  "The angle is close to zero, $\cos$ should be close to one" wouldn't have been enough intuition to catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you are working in degrees or radians. It's just a case of units.

When we think about length, we have $1 \, \text{km} = 1,000\,\text{m}$.

When we talk about velocity we have $1 \, \text{km/h} = \tfrac{8}{15}\text{m/s}$.

When we talk about angles we have $180^{\circ} = \pi^c$.

**However**, when we are doing calculus: we must **always** use radians.

The usual definition of cosine is in terms of the ratio of the adjacent and the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle. In this case, degrees or radians are fine. There is another "definition" of the cosine function which comes from the Taylor Series:

$$\cos x \sim 1 - \tfrac{1}{3!}x^3 + \tfrac{1}{5!}x^5 - \tfrac{1}{7!}x^7 + \cdots $$

This definition depends on differentiation, i.e. on using calculus. Hence: you must use radians.